# Xamarin entry control TextChanged event looping round

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, logic

On my form I have 3 `entry` controls. I'm trying to validate the 'Age' control, with the following validation rules:

- Cannot enter more than 3 digits
- Cannot enter a decimal place (.)
- Cannot enter a hyphen (-)

To do this, I've set the 'TextChanged' property of my control to be

```
TextChanged="OnAgeTextChanged"
```

My `OnAgeTextChanged` method is:

```
 private void OnAgeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       var entry = (Entry)sender;

        try
        {

           if (entry.Text.Length > 3)
            {
               string entryText = entry.Text;

               entry.TextChanged -= OnAgeTextChanged;

                entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
                entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;
            }

            string strName = entry.Text;

            if (strName.Contains(".") || strName.Contains("-"))
            {
                strName = strName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
                entry.Text = strName;
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex);
        }

    }
```

However, when the if conditions are met, the event is being looped over multiple times, causing the application to run slowly.

For example, if I enter my age as 1234, it loops over the code multiple times so there's a delay, with the delay increasing each time the text gets changed.

What other way can I achieve this validation, but without the event being called multiple times?

**EDIT**

After updating the code to remove the `TextChanged` trigger on my control before re-assigning it at the end of the method, it still loops over multiple times, and the number of loops increases with each key press.

Entry control `xaml`

```
<Entry x:Name="txtAge"
       Placeholder="Age"
       Keyboard="Numeric"
       TextColor="DarkBlue"
       PlaceholderColor="DarkBlue"
       Completed="AgeCompleted"
       HorizontalOptions="Start"
       WidthRequest="55"
       TextChanged="OnAgeTextChanged"
/>
```

`TextChanged` event

```
 private void OnAgeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var entry = (Entry)sender;

        try
        {

            entry.TextChanged -= OnAgeTextChanged;

            if (entry.Text.Length > 3)
            {

                entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
            }

            string strName = entry.Text;

            if (strName.Contains(".") || strName.Contains("-"))
            {
                strName = strName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
                entry.Text = strName;
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex);
        }

        finally
        {

            entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;
        }
     }
```

Comment: That's because when you set `entry.Text` `OnAgeTextChanged` is going to get called again. My suggestion would be to change your validation to `entry.Unfocused` when the user should be finished editing the text that or you could unsubscribe your entry to `OnAgeTextChanged` at the start of the method then after setting all the text resubscribe at the end of the method.

Comment: @Nick how would I do the second one? I know in vb.NET I can use `RemoveHandler`, but how would it be done in c#?

Comment: You're already doing it in the method move `entry.TextChanged -= OnAgeTextChanged;` to the beginning of your try and maybe add a finally after your catch and move `entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;` there.

Comment: @Nick Hmm, it still loops over multiple times after doing as you said

Comment: Yeah, you're right for some reason when you set `entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;` the entry's text isn't actually changing on the upside at least `OnAgeTextChanged` is only being called twice now.

Comment: @Nick The amount of loops is increasing with each key press. If I enter 1, it loops once. Then adding a 2 seems to loop twice. I haven't traced an exact pattern yet but after entering 1234 it was looping a lot of times and getting really slow

Comment: I think there is a forms bug here but I'm only ever getting at max 2 loops. I'd check how you are setting TextChanged on your entry are you doing it in code and/or in xaml?

Comment: @Nick see my edit. That's the full xaml and TextChanged code. The only other code I have is on the Completed method, it sets the focus onto another control

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173234/discussion-between-nick-and-david).

Comment: honestly I'd take out the event unsubscribe and subscribe events ('entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;'), they don't work the way you think they do, not in this instance anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way that I resolved this issue in the end was using a separate class to handle my validations.

My validation class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class viewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private string age_;
 public string Age { get { return age_; } set { if (age_ != value) { age_ = ProcessAge(value); OnPropertyChanged(); } } }

 private string ProcessAge(string age)
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
        return age;

    if (age.Length > 3)
        age = age.Substring(0, 3);

    if (age.StartsWith("0"))
        age = age.Remove(0, 1);

    return age.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
 }

 private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }
}
```

Then, I can bind the form to use this class, with:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new viewModel();
    }
```

And finally, to bind the entry control to use the Age property, I set the `Text` property

```
Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

What this now does, is every time the value in the Age control changes, it will look to the Age property in the new class and see that to set it, it needs to go through `ProcessAge` to validate it, and this is where the checks are now done.

This is faster, as it only occurs once per key press and there's no fiddling around required with subscribing and unsubscribing the `TextChanged` event and no loops.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `object sender` you've received from the event is not the exact same instance of `Entry` generated by your `XAML`.

So, that can explain the issue:

> `entry.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;` has no effect to your code at all, this object have no subscribers yet

Then, at the end of your stuff, you set:

> `entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;` now it does. You're 'immortalizing' this instance (`sender`).

I'm wondering if it's an elegant way to solve your specific problem (later I'll try to post some alternatives if it works) but to make it works, I guess you can try to unsubscribe and subscribe again over the `txtAge` object reference directly:

```
private void OnAgeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txtAge.TextChanged -= OnAgeTextChanged;

        if (e.NewTextValue?.Length > 3 ?? false)
            txtAge.Text = e.OldTextValue;

        string strNumber = txtAge.Text;

        if (strNumber.Contains(".") || strNumber.Contains("-"))
        {
            strNumber = strNumber.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
            txtAge.Text = strNumber;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        txtAge.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;
    }
 }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
private void OnAgeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var entry = (Entry)sender;
   entry.TextChanged -= OnAgeTextChanged;
    try
    { //[...] Your stuff
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //[...] Your other stuff
    }
    finally{
          entry.TextChanged += OnAgeTextChanged;
    }
}
```

Because in the code below, you change the text while the event handler is still listening, so it will be fired again at least 1 time.

```
if (strName.Contains(".") || strName.Contains("-"))
{
    strName = strName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
    entry.Text = strName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the entry unfocused event, this way it won't make so many calls to the event handler and hence the performance will be improved!